# My View is very slow drawing drawables

Tags: android, view, draw, drawable

I am trying to draw a **ball animation over the camera**, that is the reason I have to use class View instead of SurfaceView. The point is that is when I run my app, animation is drawing properly sometimes, but if I back to the earlier activity, and return to it, ball **draws very slow**.
To call the OnDraw method I use the acelerometer:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        mView.invalidate();
    }       

}
```

An that`s my OnDraw method:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();

    parabolic.getPositions();
    int positionY = parabolic.pixY;
    int positionX = parabolic.pixX;

    ball.setBounds(positionX, positionY,
            (int) (positionX + ball.getIntrinsicWidth()),
            (int) (positionY + ball.getIntrinsicHeight()));

    ball.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Where parabolic is an object that I inizialize in the init method:

```
ParabolicMove parabolic = new ParabolicMove();
```

And ball is a drawable:

```
ball = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);
```

How could I optimize it do draw well the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a static image to draw the image and the ball in a diferent thread. This may resolve your problem. For more information you can use SurfaceView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html